# Finding $u(x)$ using Green's Function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $(Lu)(x)= -\frac{d}{dx}\big(\frac{1}{x} \frac{du}{dx} )$ where $u(x)$ is twice differentiable function defined on $[1,2]$.

A) I need to find Green's function $G(x,t)$ such that for any $h(x)$ defined on $[1,2]$ the solution to the boundary value problem

$Lu=h$ for $1\le x \le2$

$u(1)=u^{'}(2)=0 $

is given by $u(x)=\int_1^2G(x,t)h(t)dt= \int_1^xG(x,t)h(t)dt+\int_x^2G(x,t)h(t)$.

B) Let $h(x)=x$. Use the Green's function $G(x,t)$ to find the solution $u(x)$.

So here's what I have:

$\frac{1}{x}\frac{du}{dx}=A$

$\frac{du}{dx}=Ax$

$du=Axdx$

$u(x)=\frac{Ax^2}{2}+B$

$u(1)=\frac{A}2+B=0 \Rightarrow B=-\frac{A}2$

So $u(x)=\frac{Ax^2}{2}-\frac{A}2$

$u_1(x)=\frac{x^2}2$

$u^{'}(x)=2Ax$

$u^{'}(2)=4A=0 \Rightarrow A=0$ so $U_2(x)=B=1$

Now calculating $ c=p(x)   \begin{vmatrix}
        u_1 & u_2  \\
        u_1^{'}  & u_2^{'} \\
        \end{vmatrix}$ where $p(x)=-\frac1{x}$.

$c= -\frac1{x} \begin{vmatrix}
        \frac{x^2}2 & 1  \\
        2x  & 0 \\
        \end{vmatrix}=-\frac1{x}(-x)=1$

So green's function yields

$G(x,t)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{c}u_1(t)u_2(x)  & \text 1 \le t \le x\\
\frac1{c}u_1(x)u_2(t)  & \text x \le t \le 2\\
\end{cases}$

$G(x,t)=\begin{cases}
(\frac1{1})\frac{t^2}2 (1)  & \text 1 \le t \le x\\
(\frac1{1})\frac{x^2}2 (1)  & \text x \le t \le 2\\
\end{cases}$

Therefore, with $h(t)=t$

$u(x)=\int_1^2G(x,t)h(t)dt= \int_1^x\frac{t^2}2tdt+\int_x^2\frac{x^2}2t dt$.

After integrating, I obtain

$u(x)=\frac{x^4}8-\frac{x^2}8+x^2-\frac{x^4}4$

But then the boundary conditions do not hold. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: The correct formula for the Green's function is 
$$G(x,t) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}(x^2-1), & x\le t \\
\frac{1}{2}(t^2-1), & t\le x. 
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Whoa how did u get this?

Comment: what were you functions for the Wronskian is my question?

Comment: This equation works but I'm having trouble setting it up

Comment: @Zuniga: You're very close. Just notice that $u_1(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$, not $\frac{x^2}{2}$. Your equation for $u_2(x)$ is fine.

Comment: I got it nevermind! I know where I messed up!!